# Failed to read schema document

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I made a webapplication in order to execute specific reports which are hosted on `JasperServer`. Some reports are linked with hyperlinks type of "ReportExecution" and report parameter as _report. The hyperlinks are put on fields of my reports. while compiling that jrxml file in java i am getting error like below

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: 
Failed to read schema document 'http://jaspersoft.com/schema/fusion.xsd', because 
1) could not find the document; 
2) the document could not be read;
3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

Could any one plz help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add jasperreports-fusion.jar to solve this issue. You can find the jar in following location ireport installation directory\ireportpro\modules\ext

Comment: Where to put this jar?